# How to get a full list of schemas in pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

How can I get a full list of schemas in known database Postgresql in pg_dump utility to backup each schema in a separate file?

Now I use it in this way:

```
# pg_dump my_database
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
psql -c "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata" -At
```

to return just the names, i.e., suitable for shell scripting.